# mySQL adding functionality to search function

Tags: php, mysql, search

This mySQL query searches for items in a wordpress database looking for similarities in the title.

```
SELECT ID, post_name, post_title, post_date 
FROM wp_posts 

WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$my_text%' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

I have expanded it to include tags as well.

```
SELECT ID, post_name, post_title, post_date 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
ON        object_id = wp_posts.id
LEFT JOIN wp_terms 
ON        term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id

WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$my_text%'

OR wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%$my_text%'
```

This too works but it adding to the query the number of times a post can be fetched. For example, if we type in a search term that appears only in the title, but the same post ID is in the tag table for four unrelated tags, it fetches the post from the title similarity four times not one. Obviously this query needs some tweaking but I am very new to mySQL and need a hand.

Comment: You may need the UNION clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful link for UNION selects: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
...  WHERE 
wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND (wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$my_text%' OR wp_terms.name LIKE '%$my_text%')
```